# Differential equation with first derivative squared

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How does one solve this type of differential equation?

$C_1(\dot{x})^2 + \dfrac{C_2}{C_3-x} = C_4$

Where the C's are all constants? Thanks.

Comment: What if you simply and take square roots? $x'' = \pm \sqrt{...}$.

Comment: Where is this monster coming from ?

Comment: It's a physics situation using kinetic energy and electric potential energy between two particles. Say we have 2 positively charged particles. One to the left which is moving to the right with some velocity. The particle to the right is motionless held fixed. the differential equation is for the motion of the left particle using conservation of energy. The left particle starts at x=0 at t=0 with some initial velocity. moving towards the second particle which is located at $x=C_3$

Comment: I should be very surprised by an analytical solution. Consider the problem  numerically.

Comment: The kinetic energy usually depends on the square of the *first* derivate, not the second...?

Comment: @HansLundmark, yes you're absolutely right. Thanks. I've corrected it.

Comment: Thus... $$\sqrt{\frac{a-x}{b-x}}\cdot\dot x=\pm c,$$ for some suitable constants $(a,b,c)$, that is, a separable equation which can be integrated to yield an implicit formula for $x(t)$ of the form $$\int_{x(0)}^{x(t)}\sqrt{\frac{a-z}{b-z}}\,dz=\pm ct.$$